# Not able to increase audio pitchrate in safari browser

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, audio, safari

I am facing one strange issue regarding pitch rate in safari browser. I am not able to increase the pitch rate of audio file if audio is coming through Java servlet. However it is working fine if audio is coming directly from server.

Kindly check [`my working code`](http://jsfiddle.net/udeshvirk/xwgxjssb/6/), where audio is coming directly from server.

Below is Java Servlet code:

```
response.setContentType("audio/mpeg");
   response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(epubFile.length()));
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + epubFile.getName() + "\"");
   BufferedInputStream input = null;
   BufferedOutputStream output = null;

   try {
    // Open streams.
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(epubFile), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

    // Write file contents to response.
    byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int length;
    while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
     output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
   } finally {
    // Gently close streams.
    close(output);
    close(input);
   }
```

If i render same audio file through servlet, then pitchrate is not going above 1, however below 1 is working fine.

Hope someone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance,

Udesh

Comment: You don't show your servlet code or the url to it in your web page.  The difference is probably to do with the http headers being sent from the server with the data stream. wireshark traffic snag of the servlet/file over http would show why the pitchrate isn't going above 1.

Comment: Sorry man, I have posted the java servlet code in my question now.